# Estimate conversion rate over time using different overall mean

Tags: forecasting

I have to estimate conversion rate of visitors of a website for the next day.

The forecasted value has several input parameters:

- Website
- is Weekend/Workday (Yes, No),
- Month (1-12)
- Week of the year (1-52)

I have historical data in a table like this

| Website | Weekend/Workday | Month | Week of the year | Clicks | Orders | Conversion rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google.it | Weekend | 12 | 50 | 10 | 1 | 10% |
| Google.it | Workday | 10 | 40 | 100 | 5 | 5% |
| Google.it | Workday | 1 | 3 | 20 | 1 | 5% |

Now I can compute the overall mean for each when I sum clicks/orders by each paramenter and calculate the historical conversion rate.
For example, aggregating by **weekend/workday** I can get

| Website | Weekend/workday | clicks | Orders | Conversion rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google.it | Workday | 120 | 6 | 5% |
| Google.it | Weekend | 10 | 1 | 10% |

or by **month**

| Website | Month | clicks | Orders | Conversion rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google.it | 1 | 20 | 1 | 5% |
| Google.it | 10 | 100 | 5 | 5% |
| Google.it | 12 | 10 | 1 | 10% |

Now my question is, what model could I use to estimate the conversion rate for the next data point having as input all those overall means?

For example, I would estimate the conversion rate for tomorrow (Workday/Weekend=Workday, month=11, Week=45) = ?

My idea is to calculate the overall mean by website (all time conversion rate) and then isolate the effect of weekends, month and Week seasonalities. But I have more components of seasonality and they are dependent each other so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: How does it look like when you plot it as a time series? E.g. the conversion rate on weekdays or weekends as function of the week. If that looks like a well behaved function then fit some reasonable estimate and extrapolate it.

Comment: To me, the question is poorly stated. Could it be due to a lack of understanding of the topics involved? Is this AB testing or Logit,..., I don't see any mention of either. Think back to your original question. What is important to investigate? If this is due tomorrow then may I suggest starting with taking the entire dataset and doing one test by whatever test looks most appropriate in your situation. Again, you need to sharpen yr question.

Comment: Yes, sorry I don’t know much about topic I would like a direction. It’s not A/B testing, is forecasting a new conversion rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend fitting a logistic regression model.  It could be much more complicated than this, and could incorporate more seasonality components if desired.

$$\rm \ln\left(\frac{\frac{orders}{clicks}}{1-\frac{orders}{clicks}} \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 type + \beta_2 week + \beta_3 month$$

where $\beta_1$ is a coefficient on type={0,1}, $\beta_2$ is really a family of coefficients on a dummy encoded week, and $\beta_3$ is a family of coefficients on a dummy encoded month.

Here is how that is accomplished in R:

```r
require(lubridate)
  
# simulate data
set.seed(18093)
data <- data.frame(website = factor(rep(c("google", "yahoo", "apple"), times = 180)),
                   date = rep(as.Date("2022-01-01")+1:60, each = 3),
                   clicks = rpois(180*3, 100),
                   orders = rbeta(180*3, 1, 10))
data$orders <- floor(data$orders * data$clicks)
data$rate <- data$orders / data$clicks
data$type <- factor(ifelse(lubridate::wday(data$date, label = TRUE) %in% c("Sat","Sun"), "Weekend", "Weekday"))
data$month <- factor(lubridate::month(data$date, label = TRUE))
data$week <- factor(lubridate::week(data$date))

# fit a generalized linear model
glm1 <- glm(cbind(orders, clicks) ~ type + month + week, family = binomial(link = "logit"),
            data = data)

# predict on a new day  Google, Weekday, week 7, month Feb
predict(glm1, newdata = data.frame(website = factor("google", levels = levels(data$website)), 
                               type = factor("Weekday", levels = levels(data$type)), 
                                   week = factor(7, levels = levels(data$week)), 
                               month = factor("Feb", levels = levels(data$month))),
        type = "response")
#>          1 
#> 0.09054071
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: OP, a logistic regression model exactly does exactly what you are after - incorporating the effect of each variable, whilst taking account of the dependencies between variables